# Meaning of the phrase "Glob up in lines" in an advertisement video of Olay products

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I watched an advertisement video of Olay (32 seconds) via youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYstgkG6mxc and this is the transcript of the video:

> Inner beauty is important, but not nearly as important as outer
> beauty. That's why I use CoverGirl's Simply Ageless Makeup with Olay
> Regenerist Serium.  A liquid makeup can **glob up in lines** and wrinkles
> and make you look older.  Simply Ageless stays suspended over lines
> and makes you look amazing. Simply Ageless from Olay. I'm easy,
> breezy, beautiful, CoverGirl. And to look really amazing, start with
> my Serum Primer.

I have looked up the word "glob" in many dictionaries such as Oxford, Longman but they only show the meanings of "glob" as a noun, like:

> A lump of a semi-liquid substance
>
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/glob

Could you help explain the meaning of the phrasal verb "glob up in" and provide me some similar example sentences (if possible)?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ***glob*** as a verb is relatively uncommon. OED, for example, only lists it as a *noun*.

But this kind of "ad-hoc" [verbification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)#Verb_conversion_in_English) is a common feature of English. In OP's context, we could reasonably replace ***glob*** [up | together] with ***clump*** [up | together] or ***stick*** [together]. What it means here is the thick "semi-liquid" coating on a constantly-flexing surface (one's face) tends to collect in particular positions, creating lines and wrinkles (or accentuating pre-existing wrinkles in the skin).

Here are a couple more written instances...

> 1: [*He thought a salad was tomato and lettuce **globbed** with mayonnaise*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LFtVAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22globbed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jGBWVJXNEKjjsAS0toDgAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22globbed%22&f=false)
>    2: [*One held his arms as another **globbed** petroleum jelly up his nostrils*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BO97khe7iTUC&pg=PA73&dq=%22globbed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jGBWVJXNEKjjsAS0toDgAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22globbed%22&f=false)

As you can see, the exact nature of the (verb) action involving (noun) *globs* varies across the three examples. And the preposition ***up*** in my second example is *required* rather than *optional* (the globs are being *pushed **up*** someone's nostrils). Basically, you need to determine from context precisely what kind of action involving globs is being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

To "glob up" means to form a glob - as you said, a lump of semi-liquid substance.  Another example of something that might glob would be mud, grease, or sauce.  Glob is almost always used for something gross.

When the ad says "lines and wrinkles", it is talking about the normal folds and crevices of a face, especially one showing signs of age. Makeup companies would like you to believe that this is also gross.

In other words, if you have lines and wrinkles, you probably feel gross and try to cover it up with makeup.  If you get the wrong kind of makeup, it will make your lines and wrinkles even more gross by globbing up inside of them.  Don't risk being gross, buy this specific makeup!  ;D